# How to add own modules in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I Want to create my own customized modules in Shopify when customers is logged in.

Example: I would to show near by doctors through the map.

Is it possible to do in Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You would install a custom App that would contain a list of doctors and locations. You would create a Proxy in the App so you could make a secure callback to the endpoint. As data, you'd send the customer ID. Using the customer ID, the App would get the customer's location. The data you return would be the matching doctors.

Very common to do this with Shopify.